# How to implement a timer?

Tags: php

For a project I need a timer in PHP such that starts when first page opens (say 1.php) and stops when I go to second page (say 2.php). How I can do this in PHP?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start and stop a timer PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310487/start-and-stop-a-timer-php)

Comment: for php questions look first to http://php.net/

Comment: @Stefan That's like saying, "for .NET questions look first to msdn.microsoft.com" for any .NET question. Maybe the OP did go to PHP.net first, and a search for "timer between 2 php pages" didn't turn up any results. If only one could downvote a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Very*** basic example:

1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['start'] = time();
?>
```

2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['start'])){
    $timeSince = time() - $_SESSION['start'];
    echo $timeSince . ' seconds since user first loaded 1.php!';
    unset($_SESSION['start']); //unset the timer variable.
} else{
    //didn't visit 1.php or session has expired. You could force a redirect:
    header('Location: 1.php');
    exit;
}
?>
```

It is worth noting that:

1. You can't ensure that the user will travel from 1.php to 2.php. They could close their browser or hit the back button. Their session could expire.
2. You might want to force a redirect from 2.php back to 1.php if the start session variable isn't present.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [microtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) function.